# What is the specification of control cap (control tower) glass in FAA?

Tags: aircraft-design, faa-regulations, air-traffic-control

Does anyone know where I can find the specification of glass for control tower?

Answer (score 3):

[UFGS 08 88 58](https://www.wbdg.org/FFC/DOD/UFGS/UFGS%2008%2088%2058.pdf) - AIR TRAFFIC CONTROL TOWER CAB GLASS

> This guide specification covers the
> requirements for engineered outward sloping low-iron
> clear annealed tower cab glass for use in military
> air traffic control towers.

Also see §151 in [FAA Order 6480.7](https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/order/6480.7d.pdf) - AIRPORT TRAFFIC CONTROL TOWER AND
TERMINAL RADAR APPROACH CONTROL FACILITY DESIGN GUIDELINES.

> 151. WINDOW GLASS